# Square of MAD as variance equivalent

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, mad

I have to estimate the error of a 1D array. The usual way of doing this to take the SD of it and square it.

The issue is the following:

The values in the array represent the time series of the intensity of a source. Whilst the source is mostly quiescent, there are times for which the source becomes active (the values increase/decrease). Whilst there are some constraints on when that is, one cannot be quite sure. I thus thought of taking the median absolute deviation MAD instead of the SD of the values during quiescence phase ... and then square them ?

Comment: Why take the square?

Comment: Because one usually would take the variance as estimate of the error, right?

Comment: STD = sexually transmitted disease, for many. Better to say SD or standard deviation.

Comment: In general (other than trivialities such as MAD(constant) = SD(constant) = 0) the only safe statement is that MAD and SD have the same units and dimensions (and their squares do too). What their relationship is (is usually) depends on the distribution being sampled from and it's not even guaranteed to hinge on a multiplicative factor to be determined. One might expect MAD to be less sensitive to outliers and long tails; whether in turn that's a feature depends on what you want of either measure.

Comment: So under the (very long shot in my case) assumption that my signal is normally distributed during the quiescent phase (and possible 'flaring' is cut away  as outlier by MAD), i have to use the (from wiki) multiplicative factor of 1.4826 to get the std and than square it ?

Comment: As error estimates, SDs or MADs have the advantage of being in the same scale as the measurement of interest. Variances or other squared error estimates are not. Check the statistical software that you use; R, at least, includes the 1.4826 factor as the default.

Comment: @EdM thanks for the hint, indeed python statsmodel includes the constant already. So now a more delicate question: In case my signal is not normal is there a robust way of estimating the normalization constant?
My signal is the median subtracted signal of the the time sequence and thus should only include noise +  what ever the source does in the quiescence phase. So far I evaluated it to be in part be: white detector +  shot for high n --> white +  *pointing offset confusion noise* which i don't understand (and nobody else does afaik)